# Gluon View lifecycle

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I have a Service class where I attached a listener to `MobileApplication.viewProperty`to keep track of the previous / current `View`.
When I switch back to a different `View` I want to check the name of this `View`, to perform some tasks according to it.
While in the views `onHidden` handler the `viewProperty` is already updated with the new views value, the listener in my Service class will only be called after `onHidden`. What could be the reason for this?

```
public class GluonApplication extends MobileApplication {

private static final String SECONDARY_VIEW = "secondary";

private String              previousView;
private String              currentView;

@Override
public void init() {

    addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, () ->
    {
        Button btn = new Button("next view");
        btn.setOnAction(e -> switchView(SECONDARY_VIEW));

        View view = new View(new StackPane(btn)) {
            @Override
            protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
                appBar.setTitleText("Home");
            }
        };

        return view;
    });

    addViewFactory(SECONDARY_VIEW, () ->
    {
        Button btnBack = new Button("go back");
        btnBack.setOnAction(e -> switchView("home"));

        View view = new View(new StackPane(btnBack)) {
            {
                setOnHidden(e ->
                {
                    System.out.println("viewProperty: " + viewProperty().get().getName() + " viewListener:" + currentView);

                    if (currentView.equals("myView")) {
                        // action
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
                appBar.setTitleText("Secondary");
            }
        };

        return view;
    });

    viewProperty().addListener((ov, v, v1) ->
    {
        if (v != null) {
            previousView = v.getName();
        }
        currentView = v1.getName();
        System.out.println("listener previousView: " + previousView + " view: " + currentView);
    });

}

@Override
public void postInit(Scene scene) {
    ((Stage) scene.getWindow()).setAlwaysOnTop(true);
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see what's your point here. Do you mean that `View::setOnHidden` should be called *after* `viewProperty` changes?

Comment: I was just confused about the `viewProperty` already showing the value of the next view, while still in `View::setOnhidden` and the according listener not being updated.

Comment: Following your sample,  if you are on the primary view and click the button, its `view.setOnHidden` listener is called first, then the secondary view `view.setOnShowing` listener is called, and finally the global `viewProperty` will report the change to the secondary view.